# JSP Ignoring some tags

Tags: java, html, css, jsp

I'm working in a school project in which i have to display the products for an online store with JSP. The problem is that when I try to get them, JSP is 'ignoring' some of the HTML tags that im telling him to print.

Here's my code:

```
`<%
   if (datos != null)
    {
      int contador = 0;
      out.print("<table >");
      out.println("<tr>");

      for (int i = 0; i < datos.length; i++)
                                {
      /* for (int j = 0; j < datos[i].length; j++)
      {*/
      out.print("<div class=\"cajaProducto\">");
      out.print("<img class=\"imgProducto\" src=\"../" + datos[i][6] + "\">");
      out.print(" <h5 class=\"nombreProducto\" name=\"txtnombreProducto\">" + datos[i][1] +"</h5>");
      out.print("<h3 class=\"precioProducto\">$"+ datos[i][5] +"</h3>");
      String string = "<form class=\"pedirProducto\" action=\"agregarCarrito.jsp?idproducto="+ datos[i][0] +"\">" + "<ul>"+
      "<li><a class=\"btnMenos\" href=\"javascript:disminuir(" + datos[i][0] +");\">-</a></li>" +
      "<li><input class=\"txtcantidad\" type=number name=\"cantidad" + datos[i][0] +"\" value=\"1\" id=\"cantidad" + datos[i][0] +"\"></li>"+
      "<li><a class=\"btnMas\" href=\"javascript:aumentar(" + datos[i][0] +");\">+</a></li>" +
      "</ul><br>" + "<center>  <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Agregar al carrito\" class=\"boton\"></center>" +
      "</form></div></td>";
                                                
                                        
      out.print(string);
                                     
      contador = contador + 1;
      /*}*/
     if(contador == 4){
     out.println("</tr>");
                                                                           out.println("<tr>");

     contador = 0;
     }else{
                                        
      }
                                    
      }
      }`
```

And here's the HTML that I'm getting back:

```
 <div id="columnaContenido">
            
                              <div class="cajaProducto">
<img class="imgProducto" src="../img/productos/2.jpg">
 <h5 class="nombreProducto" name="txtnombreProducto">Max Steel edición de lujo</h5>
<h3 class="precioProducto">$139.0</h3>
<form class="pedirProducto" action="agregarCarrito.jsp?idproducto=2"></form>
<ul>
<li><a class="btnMenos" href="javascript:disminuir(2);">-</a></li>
<li><input class="txtcantidad" type="number" name="cantidad2" value="1" id="cantidad2"></li>
<li><a class="btnMas" href="javascript:aumentar(2);">+</a></li></ul><br>
<center>  <input type="submit" value="Agregar al carrito" class="boton"></center></div>
```

As you see, I want to have nested tables for my design, but the HTML ignores the second table tag.
Also, I have a form that allows me to add a product, and it has 3 "buttons" to modify the quantity, but the form closes right after it opens, so it doesn't include the  in which the buttons are...

I hope you can help me. :)

Comment: Please, post your code within the post. The link may die, but the code you would have pasted within your question will not.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I'm derp. I was missing a < td > inside the for, i typed it in and everything works now. 
Pd. Sorry for the question, i was getting desperate.